# variable definition ignored in makefile

Tags: makefile

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific):

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when
>   you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in
>   effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their
>   prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable
>   with their own target-specific variable value).

Trying the following makefile:

```
all::
    @: '$@'

all:: dep;

dep:
    echo target is: $(target)


all : target = all

.PHONY: all dep
```

And runing:

```
$ make -j
```

I get:

```
echo target is: 
target is:
```

Where did the definition `target = all` go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `make` instead of `make -j` the output is

```
echo target is: all
target is: all
```

I don't know why you need to specify `-j` but my initial guess is that by providing `-j` make is executing each `all` recipe as a **separate job** and thus the variable `target = all` is **not set** in the **same job** that runs

```
all:: dep;

dep:
    echo target is: $(target)
```

hence why `$target` is empty and the output is

```
echo target is: 
target is:
```